# percise animation in blender

Tags: animation

[image]I try to make a mechanical keyboard showreel animation, which includes a exploded view animation. In order to do that, I need to keep all the objects seperately and in percise position as much as possible. Most of the models ( except the keycap, the switches and the stabs ) were built in fusion 360 and I imported it into blender as OBJ files. I have successfully  arranged all the componets for the keyboard except the keycap. I dowloaded the keycap blender model from the internet. When I tried to copy it into my keyboard file, they were not on the same scale. And when I tried to rescale those, all the components, which I have arranged in percise position before, messed up, so I do not khow what to do now. Are there ways to make all the objects be on the same scale without being messed up ? Btw, I am new to blender.

Comment: Select all the objects in Object mode with 'A' then Ctrl-A > Scale to apply the scale.

Comment: can be different reasons and unfortunately you didn't show us important informations, e.g. are there objects parented? maybe, because you are a beginner it would be quicker if u provide your blend file so we can check it out and tell u what the reason is

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of one specific object prior to scaling, what steps you've taken to scale it (in edit mode or object mode?) and what the result is. In addition to the other comments I would recommend to check that the objects origin matches the geometry, otherwise scaling will move the geometry as well. You can use //Object > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry// to fix this.

Comment: thanks you. I will you a link to my blender files. Hope you can check it out. https://www.mediafire.com/file/96hm4luiekhubjk/untitled.blend/file

Comment: and this one https://www.mediafire.com/file/ns5qoq94xbgyq2n/ansi_cherry.blend/file

Comment: @RobertGützkow I did all my work in object mode. Firstly, I chose all the objects I need to scale, then I changed the scale number ( in all 3 dimensions ),  then I applied it to all the objects which I have selected.